# Find the formula to express the relationship between these series of numbers

Tags: geometry

thank you for taking the time.

I'm working on creating a model my team can use to see the maximum number of miles that can be added to a delivery trip in a measured area based on the number of stops (I will call them points in my problem). I have a set of numbers that I've arrived at logically, but I can't seem to turn their relationship into a formula. Hoping someone can help.

Imagine a square area measuring 22.75 miles on each side. And our starting point is one of the corners of the square, we'll call it P0. When I add a delivery point (p1), where can I add it within the square that would create the longest line (maximum miles)? It would be the diagonal point across, and that distance would be 32.17miles ($22.75*\sqrt{2}$). The idea is to place the point the farthest away possible from all other points. The next two points I could add would be 22.75 miles away from any other point, because I need to place them at the corners. Thus, P2 and P3 add 22.75miles. P4 would be in the center of P0, P1, P2, and P3. So p4 would add 16.085 miles ($\frac{32.17}{2}$) to the trip. Now P5, P6, P7, and P8 can all be placed within similar quadrants that make them equidistant from points most near them. They would all add 8.0425 miles ($\frac{16.085}{2}$). P9, P10, P11, P12 would be the same situation, they would all add 4.02125 miles ($\frac{8.0425}{2}$).

So you can see the series of numbers I've found logically. Here they are.

[See:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlDrN.png)

I can't seem to find a way to turn them into a formula. After P5, things become clear: every four stops, the maximum miles added by a stop are half of what it was 4 stops ago. But I can't even figure out how to express that in a formula, and if I did, there's still the problem of the first 4 stops not behaving that way. Hope this makes sense. I tried my best.

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

We are interested in the maximum distance *to the nearest point* that can be added per stop. The placement of the first four corner points is trivial so they will not be counted (what you called $P_4$ will be stop number $0$). After that we add stops in the middle between other points as shown:

[image]

Call all points with the same distance to their neighbors a "set". $a_n$ is the number of stops in the $n$th set that all add a distance of $d_n$ given a square of sidelength $1$:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc} n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ \hline
a_n & 1 & 4 & 4 & 12 & 16 & 40 & 64 & 144 & 256 \\ d_n & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{8}  & \frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{16} & \frac{1}{16\sqrt{2}} \end{array}$$
$$d_n = 2^{-\frac{n+1}{2}} \qquad a_n = \begin{cases} 2^n \qquad \qquad \text{ if } n \text{ is even} \\ 2^n + 2^\frac{n+1}{2} \quad \, \text{if } n \text{ is odd} \end{cases}$$

Given a stop number $x$ we first compute the current set number $n$ and plug that into the equation for $d_n$. To do this we first calculate the partial sums depending on weather we stop at odd or even values of $n$:

$$s_\text{odd} = \sum_{i = 0}^\frac{n-1}{2} a_{2i} + a_{2i+1} = 2^{n+1} + 2^\frac{n+3}{2} - 3 \qquad n = \log_2 \left( \frac{s-2\sqrt{s+4}+5}{2} \right) := f(s)$$
$$s_\text{even} = a_0 + \sum_{i = 0}^\frac{n}{2} a_{2i-1} + a_{2i} = 2^{n+1} + 2^{\frac{n}{2}+1} - 3 \qquad n = \log_2 \left( \frac{s-\sqrt{2s+7}+4}{2} \right) := g(s)$$
$$n = \begin{cases} \lceil f(x) \rceil \quad \text{if } \lfloor f(x) \rfloor \text{ is even} \\ \lceil g(x) \rceil \quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}  \quad \approx \log_2(x) - 1 \quad \text{for large }x \; \to d \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

---

Let's see how much the $30$th stop adds: $f(30) = 3.7 \quad g(30) = 3.5$
$\lfloor f(x) \rfloor$ is odd so the current $n = \lceil g(x) \rceil = 4 \quad$, so $d = \frac{22.75}{4 \sqrt{2}} = 4.02$ miles
the approximation yields $d = \frac{22.75}{\sqrt{30}} = 4.15$ miles.

If you want to count the first four points you can add $22.75 \cdot (2 + \sqrt{2}) = 64.35$ miles to that.

Comment: #1 - I assume that we'll drive to p3 from p0 or p1 because that's the logical way our delivery trip would go when we're making deliveries. If we have four points, we would logically go from p0>p3>p1>p2 or something like that (no diagonal trip). But when there is only one point, the maximum distance must be the diagonal p0>p1. #2: I think p4 would be half a diagonal away from other points yes? That's greater than a side length, yes? #3: Yes, but I'm trying to measure the max miles ADDED to trip per stop. So plug in stop #777 (ex) and the formula would give # of miles added to the trip.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarifying questions and diagrams you've put here @Christian.

Comment: will you please share the tool you used to make these diagrams? Thanks.

Comment: I used GeoGebra for the original diagrams